# How to parse dates in JSON request with NestJs @Body

Tags: javascript, json, date, nestjs

I have a DTO that looks like this:

```js
class PersonDto {
   readonly name: string;
   readonly birthDate: Date;
}
```

My NestJs controller method looks like this:

```js
@Post
create(@Body() person: PersonDto) {
    console.log("New person with the following data:", person);
    // more logic here
}
```

The JSON data that gets posted has `birthDate` as a string: `"2020-01-15"`. How can I convert this string to a JavaScript `Date` object? I'd like to add the `@IsDate` class-validation to `PersonDto` but currently that would fail.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I figured out how to use the global `ValidationPipe` with a Date property and the `@IsDate()` annotation:

The first step is to allow transformations like this (my bootstrap file as an example):

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Then you need to annotate the DTO with the `@Type()` annotation:

```js
import { IsDate } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

class PersonDto {
   readonly name: string;
   @Type(() => Date)
   @IsDate()
   readonly birthDate: Date;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Any clues ?

Comment: @r3dm4n make sure you apply the attributes on a class.