# Transform the @Body without requiring it in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

What I basically want to do is to parse the date string from the request to a Date object like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240298/how-to-parse-dates-in-json-request-with-nestjs-body).

However, this is not my use case because in my case the date is not required. So if I use the solution from the question above it responds with a 400: `due must be a Date instance`.

This is my DTO:

```
export class CreateTaskDto {
    @IsDefined()
    @IsString()
    readonly name: string;

    @IsDefined()
    @IsBoolean()
    readonly done: boolean;

    @Type(() => Date)
    @IsDate()
    readonly due: Date;
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
@Post('tasks')
async create(
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
    createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto
): Promise<TaskResponse> {
    const task = await this.taskService.create(createTaskDto);
    return this.taskService.fromDb(task);
}
```

Post request with this payload is working fine:

```
{
    "name":"task 1",
    "done":false,
    "due": "2021-07-13T17:30:11.517Z"
}
```

This request however fails:

```
{
    "name":"task 2",
    "done":false
}
```

```
{
   "statusCode":400
   "message":["due must be a Date instance"],
   "error":"Bad Request"
}
```

Is it somehow possible to tell nestjs to ignore transformation if there is no date?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but did you try making the `due` field optional? -- ex, `Date | undefined`

Comment: You should add `@IsOptional()` to the property. Let me know if that works

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes it works. I was unaware of that decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @IsOptional()
>
> Checks if given value is empty (=== null, === undefined) and if so, ignores all the validators on the property.
>
> https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators

```js
  @Type(() => Date)
  @IsDate()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly due?: Date;
```